# Resize single character from certain font

Tags: fonts, characters, resize

I use `Kerkis Sans` greek font as a secondary font in my documents, for titles, paragraphs etc. As I've been testing the font I noticed that the capital greek F (Φ) is much smaller that the rest of the letters. My attempt to resize it was this

```
\documentclass[english,greek]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{txfontsb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\kerkissans}[1]{{\fontfamily{maksf}\selectfont #1}}


\begin{document}
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ\\
\kerkissans{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}\\
\kerkissans{\textbf{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}}\\
\kerkissans{\textbf{\resizebox{!}{6pt}{Φ}Φ}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problems I face are

1. This issue appears only with `Kerkis Sans` font and only when the text is bold
2. My attempt fixes the size locally

Is there a way to resize the bold `Φ` globally?

Comment: Are virtual fonts still a thing? Back in the 90s I would do this sort of thing by editing a vpl file for the font, but I don't know whether 21st century TeX systems even use vfs anymore.

Comment: @David Carlisle Sorry forgot the `graphicx` package

Comment: This looks like a font error and should be reported there rather than in the tex document

Comment: @DonHosek some things never change (which is why we can answer questions here:-) `/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/vf/public/kerkis/gksfb7t.vf`

Comment: vftovpl says `Bad VF file: Character 159 in font 0 will be ignored` which isn't a good start :(

Comment: @David Carlisle It was actually a font error jugging by egreg's answer.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unreliable, the slot 159 in the LGR encoding is empty.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bug should be reported to the maintainer of Kerkis.

In the meantime, you can do as follows:

```latex
\documentclass[english,greek]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{txfontsb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand{\kerkissans}[1]{{\fontfamily{maksf}\selectfont #1}}

\newunicodechar{Φ}{\FIXEDPHI}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\FIXEDPHI}{}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \use:c { f@family } } { maksf }
   {
    \str_if_in:enTF { \use:c { f@series } } { b }
     { \resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`A}{F} +}
     { F }
   }
   { F }
 }
\prg_generate_conditional_variant:Nnn \str_if_in:nn { e } { T, F, TF }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

\kerkissans{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}

\kerkissans{\textit{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}}

\kerkissans{\textbf{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}}

\kerkissans{\textit{\textbf{ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ}}}

\end{document}
```

I added a `+` in order to show that the fix is applied only when necessary, that is, when the font series is bold (also bold italic has the bug).

In the production version, remove the `+`:

```latex
\NewDocumentCommand{\FIXEDPHI}{}
 {
  \str_if_eq:eeTF { \use:c { f@family } } { maksf }
   {
    \str_if_in:enTF { \use:c { f@series } } { b }
     { \resizebox{!}{\fontcharht\font`A}{F} }
     { F }
   }
   { F }
 }
```

#### Output with the `+` for debugging

[image]

#### Output with the production version

[image]

Comment: Looks like the bold italic version had the same issue as debugging indicates. It seams also that the problem occurs from the font as the same issue appears also when using `XeLaTeX`.

Comment: @mac You can do the same with XeLaTeX, but substituting the three occurrences of `F` with `Φ`.